# Salvar Token de acesso

Tags: angularjs, rest

Estou desenhando uma arquitetura simples de login e estou em dúvida de onde salvar o Token de acesso do usuário.

O sistema vai ser desenvolvido em SPA utilizando AngularJS e o servidor será uma API REST ainda não definida. Quando o usuário logar no sistema, ele receberá uma chave que será seu Token de acesso para ele fazer qualquer outra operação no sistema.

Minha dúvida é como guardar esse Token no client side. Cookie é uma opção, mas não me parece seguro, já que é bem simples abrir um Cookie e ver o Token, pensei também em guardar em webstorage mas nao sei se é uma boa ideia também.

Existe algum padrão para essa situação?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um padrão, e na maioria das vezes você encontrará aplicações fazendo o armazenamento através de cookies, mas a utilização do Web Storage do HTML 5 também é frequentemente utilizada.

O que você tem que ter em mente é que, se você optar por utilizar cookies, você terá que se precaver contra CSRF e para isso é geralmente utilizado um token adicional para sincronização.

Alguns frameworks web oferecem uma forma fácil de se proteger contra CSRF e automaticamente adicionam um token de sincronização à sua UI (ASP.NET MVC por exemplo), mas ao utilizar AngularJS você estará escrevendo a sua própria UI e irá ter que codificar em JavaScript uma solução para gerenciar esse token de sincronização.

Ou seja, nesse seu caso, por você estar utilizando AngularJS, você poderia estar escolhendo o Web Storage do HTML 5 para se preocupar com um token a menos.